# Direct access warning in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

we are building an Xcode project and there are two warnings that I cannot figure out how to correct:

> (null): Direct access in ___cxx_global_var_init36 to global weak
>   symbol OFConditionConst::~OFConditionConst() means the weak symbol
>   cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different
>   translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

Has anyone else had to deal with this warning? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a iOS 6 app that I am refactoring for iOS 7, this warning did not appear when built for iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have *Symbols Hidden by Default* set to **No** in all your projects:

[image]

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it didn't work, I am still getting the warning. Seems like that is onto the right track though, I am going to continue trying to dig deeper into this one.